# How to install grunt file for bootstrap

Tags: json, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I need to install bootstrap. So far I have done step 1 succesfully. I was able to install the grunt file but step two is giving me problems for days, and I do not want to spend a next day on it.

step 1: Install grunt-cli globally with npm install -g grunt-cli

step 2: Navigate to the root /bootstrap/ directory, then run npm install. npm will look at the package.json file and automatically install the necessary local dependencies listed there.

Whenever I do npm install, I get npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory. Well I do not know how to get it to my current directory, at the comand prompt it is C:\Users\Crisp>. the bootstrap file is in this directory C:\Users\Crisp\bower_components\bootstrap. There you will see the package.json file.

I really do not know what to do! I have searched on this site for supposed answers but no one says how to change the directory or actually get it to work. There is nowhere I see how to change a directory or root director but everyone keeps saying change root directory I am not a tech man, I do not know. PLEASE I NEED HELP!

Comment: I already got my answer, just put cd folder name to get the comand prompt to excute in the correct folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for if you are following instructions in this link (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) you can go to the root directory by command line:
cd bower_components
then
cd bootstrap

just in case, to determine your current directory just type pwd

good luck
@contactmzn